# Splitting datetime.datetime to use as numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the time in datetime in a plot and therefore I need the numbers. for this purpose,  I made a function but I get an error when I use it

```
import pandas as pd
def dateformat(t):

    data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[t]})

    data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.date
    data['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.time
    return data['Dates']
    return data['Hours']
```

what I do is

```
t=datetime.now()
date,hour= dateformat(t)
```

the error

> File "", line 1, in 
>       date,hour= dateformat(t)
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two return statements in tandem as you have written. The way to go is to return two objects in one return statement. In other words,

```py
import pandas as pd

def dateformat(t):
    data = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[t]})
    data['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.date
    data['Hours'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y:%M:%D').dt.time
    return data['Dates'], data['Hours'] # Return statement
```

Then, you can unpack the result of the function as you were trying to do, since the function is designed to return two values.

```py
t = datetime.now()
date, hour = dateformat(t)
```